# Link Russian region codes and ISO 3166-2 code

Tags: region, russia

Looking at the [Federal subjects of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_subjects_of_Russia) page on Wikipedia, I see that Russian regions are listed with a region "Code".

Looking at the [ISO 3166-2:RU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:RU) I see that they also have ISO codes.

The names are translated differently, and neither page contains both "code" and ISO code.  Looking at regions at random, i see that both the code and ISO code are listed ([Adygea for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adygea), see the "License plates 01" and "ISO 3166 code  RU-AD").

Do the regions correspond?  And is there a resource to lookup the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

I compiled this lookup table.  It uses the "code" from [Federal subjects of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_subjects_of_Russia), ISO code from [ISO 3166-2:RU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:RU) and FIPS codes from [the Geonames russia page](https://www.geonames.org/RU/administrative-division-russia.html).

Here is the data is CSV format.

```
region_name,russian_name,code,iso3166,fips
"adygea, republic of","Адыгея, республика",1,ad,1
"bashkortostan, republic of","Башкортостан, республика",2,ba,8
"buryatia, republic of","Бурятия, республика",3,bu,11
altai republic,алтай республика,4,al,3
"dagestan, republic of","Дагестанская, республика",5,da,17
"Igushetia, Republic of",Ивановская область,6,in,19
kabardino-balkar republic,Кабардино-Балкарская республика,7,kb,22
Kalmykia Republic,"Калмыкия, республика",8,kl,24
karachay-cherkess republic,Карачаево-Черкесская республика,9,kc,27
"karelia, republic of","Karelia, республика",10,kr,28
komi republic,республика коми,11,ko,34
mari el republic,Республика Марий Эл,12,me,45
"mordovia, republic of","Мордовский, республика",13,mo,46
sakha (yakutia) republic,Республика Саха (Якутия) республика,14,sa,63
"north ossetia-alania, republic of","Северная Осетия-Алания, республика",15,se,68
"tatarstan, republic of","татарстан, республика",16,ta,73
Tuva Republic,республика Тыва,17,ty,79
udmurt republic,Удмуртская республика,18,ud,80
"khakassia, republic of","Хакасия, республика",19,kk,31
Chechen Republic,Чеченская республика,20,ce,12
chuvash republic,Чувашская республика,21,cu,16
altai krai,Алтайский край,22,alt,4
krasnodar krai,Краснодарский край,23,kda,38
krasnoyarsk krai,Красноярский край,24,kya,91
primorsky krai,Приморский край,25,pri,59
stavropol krai,ставропольский край,26,sta,70
khabarovsk krai,хабаровский край,27,kha,30
amur oblast,амурская область,28,amu,5
arkhangelsk oblast,Архангельская область,29,ark,6
astrakhan oblast,Астраханская область,30,ast,7
belgorod oblast,Белгородская область,31,bel,9
bryansk oblast,Брянская область,32,bry,10
vladimir oblast,владимир область,33,vla,83
volgograd oblast,Волгоградская область,34,vgg,84
vologda oblast,Вологодская область,35,vlg,85
voronezh oblast,Воронежская область,36,vor,86
ivanovo oblast,Ивановская область,37,iva,21
irkutsk oblast,Иркутская область,38,irk,20
kaliningrad oblast,Калининградская область,39,kgd,23
kaluga oblast,Калужская область,40,klu,25
kamchatka krai,Камчатский край,41,kam,92
kemerovo oblast,Кемеровская область,42,kem,29
kirov oblast,Кировская область,43,kir,33
kostroma oblast,Костромская область,44,kos,37
kurgan oblast,Курганская область,45,kgn,40
kursk oblast,Курская область,46,krs,41
leningrad oblast,ленинградская область,47,len,42
lipetsk oblast,Липецкая область,48,lip,43
Magadan Republic,Магаданская область,49,mag,44
moscow oblast,Московская область,50,mos,47
murmansk oblast,Мурманская область,51,mur,49
nizhny novgorod oblast,нижегородская область,52,niz,51
novgorod oblast,Новгородская область,53,ngr,52
novosibirsk oblast,новосибирская область,54,nvs,53
omsk oblast,Омская область,55,oms,54
orenburg oblast,Оренбургская область,56,ore,55
oryol oblast,Орловская область,57,orl,56
penza oblast,Пензенская область,58,pnz,57
perm krai,пермский край,59,per,90
pskov oblast,Псковская область,60,psk,60
rostov oblast,Ростовская область,61,ros,61
ryazan oblast,Рязанская область,62,rya,62
samara oblast,Самарская область,63,sam,65
saratov oblast,Саратовская область,64,sar,67
sakhalin oblast,Сахалинская область,65,sak,64
sverdlovsk oblast,Свердловская область,66,sve,71
smolensk oblast,Смоленская область,67,smo,69
tambov oblast,Тамбовская область,68,tam,72
tver oblast,Тверская область,69,tve,77
tomsk oblast,Томская область,70,tom,75
tula oblast,Тульская область,71,tul,76
tyumen oblast,Тюменская область,72,tyu,78
ulyanovsk oblast,Ульяновская область,73,uly,81
chelyabinsk oblast,челябинская область,74,che,13
Zabaykalsky Krai,Забайкальский край,75,zab,93
yaroslavl oblast,Ярославская область,76,yar,88
moscow,Москва,77,mow,48
saint petersburg,Санкт-Петербург,78,spe,66
Yevrev Oblast,Yevrev Oblast,79,yev,89
Yamalo-Nenetskiy avtonomnyy okrug,Ненецкий автономный округ,80,yan,87
khantia-mansia,Ханты-Мансийский автономный округ - Югра,81,khm,32
Chukotskiy avtonomnyy okrug,Чукотский автономный округ,82,chu,15
nenetsia,Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ,83,nen,50
```